# Get thread id of main thread

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I am writing a plugin. I am only allowed to run code from a spawned main thread. I can't run code on the main thread.

From my thread, is it possible to get the thread id of the main thread?

I thought to do `OpenProcess` like this below - however it seems overkill, as my process of the thread is the same.

```
/* CAUTION: ONLY WIN32
 * get the threadId of the main thread of a target process
 *
 * params:
 *     DWORD pId    processId of the target process
 *
 * return:
 *     Success      threadId
 *     Error        NULL
 */
DWORD GetMainThreadId(DWORD pId)
{
    LPVOID lpThId;

    _asm
    {
        mov eax, fs:[18h]
        add eax, 36
        mov [lpThId], eax
    }

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pId);
    if(hProcess == NULL)
        return NULL;

    DWORD tId;
    if(ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpThId, &tId, sizeof(tId), NULL) == FALSE)
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return NULL;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return tId;
}
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: FWIW, considering the code in the question, I see no reason to expect to find a thread ID at that address in the target process. I think that it is mere coincidence that your code appears to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to define what you mean by the main thread. The system itself has no such concept.

Typically though, what you mean when you say the main thread, is the thread which created the main application window. So, find the main application window. And then pass that window to [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx).

Comment: Ah thats a good idea thanks so much for the instant reply! I think the issue I might have with this is my code is running before the windows are created :(

Comment: In general, it is possible therefore that the thread which will create those windows has not yet been created. It is not necessarily the thread that was created when the process was created, that will create the windows.

Comment: Crap so the reason I needed this, failed me :( I was trying to get my mouse hook to be in my app only. I am getting error code `1429` should I make a new topic to ask about this?

Comment: `ERROR_GLOBAL_ONLY_HOOK` seems unrelated to this question

Comment: Oh shoot I just realized that. I had looked up the wrong error code >_< lol I was doing a `LL_MOUSE_HOOK`